# Understanding confusing algorithm notation

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic

I'm having trouble understanding the notation used by a book in describing a prng testing algorithm. Here are some of the snippets in question:

[image]
[image]

My confusion is: what is the significance of of `j`? It's not well defined at all. Is it supposed to be the index of the vectors? How does it not start from 0 then?

Continuing on:

[image]

[image]

I get that the left arrow is assignment. But again the algorithm is referring to `j` and only referring to `j0` and `j1`. Again, it seems like it would be the indices of j. But then I'm especially confused by the line, "Then for `j <- j, j1 - 1 ..., j0` " because it seems like it's referring to deincrementing the index of `j`, but it's subtracting from `j` itself and not the subscript.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It sais that `j` is getting values of `j1`, `j1-1`...`j0`  sequentially. Like a loop from `j1` down to `j0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that there are multiple independent uses of `j` here.  This is typical of CS texts written by mathematicians, who -- you might be surprised to learn -- are often very sloppy indeed about their notation, expecting the reader to glark all *sorts* of things from implicature and context.

In the first paragraph, the author uses `V[j]` to refer to an arbitrary element of an array *of 20-element vectors* (and j *does* start from zero).  They are defining how to fill this array of fixed-width vectors (you might find it more comfortable to think of this as a 2-dimensional array) from a 1-dimensional stream of random numbers.  Maybe it helps if I write out the first two rows of the array explicitly?

```
V0 = (Y0, Y1, Y2, ... Y19)
V1 = (Y20, Y21, Y22, ... Y39)
   ⋮
Vj = (Y[j*20], Y[j*20+1], ... Y[j*20+19])
```

In the second paragraph, `A[j]` is again an arbitrary element of an array, but it's a different, unrelated, array of floating-point numbers.

In the third and fourth paragraphs, `j`, `j0`, and `j1` appear to be three separate index variables, and the situation is made more confusing by cramming an algorithm into prose.  The author ought to have used pseudocode and chosen better variable names.  Here is an attempt to produce a pseudocode version - I deliberately kept the bad variable names, though, so you can see the correspondence.

```
Algorithm_S (m, n):
    # S1: Initialize.
    var A: float[n+1]
    var j, j0, j1: int

    for j in 0, 1, ..., n:
        A[j] ← 0
    A[1] ← 1

    # S2: Update probabilities.
    j0 ← 1
    j1 ← 1
    repeat n-1 times:
        j1 ← j1 + 1
        for j in j1, j1 - 1, ..., j0:
            A[j] ← (j/m)*A[j] + (1 + 1/m - j/m)*A[j-1]
            if A[j] < 1e-20:
                A[j] ← 0
                if j = j1: j1 ← j1 - 1
                if j = j0: j0 ← j0 + 1

    # S3: ...
```

I'm not sure this is correct, because it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me even after unpacking it like that.  The problem is probably that you only quoted the first two steps of the algorithm, so I don't know what this "auxiliary array of probabilities" will be used for and I can't tell if the code *should* do what it's doing.  Don't worry about it.

In summary: you are confused because this book is confusing.  It is not your fault.  I would recommend you find a book that is less confusing, and maybe come back to this one when you have had a good deal more practice reading math journal articles.

Comment: This helps, thanks. Im still not entirely sure the significance of `j0` and `j1`. Is it just to say that `j1` is the largest index of `j` and `j0` the smallest?

Comment: It looks like, on each iteration of the outer loop ("do step S2 exactly n-1 times"), the inner loop cycles j over all values from j1 down to j0, _inclusive_, and then one of j1 and j0 is changed for the next iteration.  Because the inner loop includes both of the endpoints, and because j1 and j0 don't _stay_ equal, it is okay that they _begin_ equal.  Maybe I will try to convert it to pseudocode after all ... after lunch. :-)  (One more thing: you said "decrementing the index of j", but j is not an indexed variable (an array) here.  j, j0, and j1 are three separate scalar variables.)

Comment: Edited my post to add the 3rd step in case you're curious, but you've already provided a lot of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`j` is a dummy variable. When you write `A[j]` for `j0 <= j <= j1` it serves as a placeholder to denote all the elements of `A` at indexes between `j0` and `j1`.

When you will program the algorithm, you will probably declare one or more loop variables to reflect this.

Comment: I'll echo the question I asked of the other commenter: what are `j0` and `j1`? Is it just to say that `j1` is the largest index of `j` and `j0` the smallest? Then how do you reconcile the line `j0 <- j1 <- 1` in the initialization step?

Comment: @Davigor: execute the algorithm by hand, starting from a data set of reasonable size.